# Dealing with .gitignore and Modified files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `Project/ProjectName.iml` file which is currently tracked as evidenced by

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   Project/ProjectName.iml
```

Additionally my `.gitignore` contains entry of `*.iml`

At this time, i'd like for git to no longer track `Project/ProjectName.iml` and ignore the fact that it was `modified`.

How can this be done please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the file in the repository, follow Headshota advise. If you want to remove the file from the repository, run

```
git rm --cached Project/ProjectName.iml
```

this way you remove the file from git index but not from the filesystem

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Project/ProjectName.iml
```

You will be able to have the file in the repo but no changes will be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove tracking the file with `git rm --cached Project/ProjectName.iml`, then .gitignore works

Comment: That command removes the file from the filesystem as well. `iml` is a project file for IntelliJ IDEA, you don't want to track it but you need to be able to see the project into the IDE

Answer (score 0):

This applies to any git project. Thank you for posting.

In my case, our hubot had some packages npm globally, some packages labeled as peer and some even missing.

```
git rm --cached -r node_modules
```

😎

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.